# SQL Query to output single column with below values in each row - 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4

Tags: sql

Need to write SQL query for getting below output with the given input table:

Input Table:

```
Col1
1
2
3
```

Output:

```
Col1
1
2
2
3
3
3
```

Comment: Now is a good time to take the [tour] and read [ask].  You need to tag with the database platform, and also show your attempts.  SO is not a free coding service, you need to show some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE(NN)AS
(
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5
)
SELECT C.NN 
FROM CTE AS C
CROSS JOIN CTE C2
WHERE C2.NN<=C.NN
```

CTE is your input table

Comment: What relation does your query have to OP's problem? Will it produce the desired result?

Comment: Direct relation. It will